# How can I format time as 12-hour but without the period indicator?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, formatting

I am trying to display times in Google Sheets without an AM/PM indicator, but with 12-hour time (not 24-hour "military-style" time). I do not need the AM/PM indicator as it is redundant in my situation.

I'm currently using a custom date and time format:

```
[Hour (1)]:[Minute (01)][AM/PM (p)]
```

...which displays 2:15 PM as "2:15p".

If I change this to:

```
[Hour (1)]:[Minute (01)]
```

...it displays 2:15 PM as "14:15". However, I do *not* want 24-hour time.

Is there any way to leave off the AM/PM indicator while still displaying the hours in 12-hour time format?

I'd rather not do the formatting in a formula (converting the values to text) as my times are consumed by formulas in other cells.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible without a formula. Separate time storing from time displaying by using one cell to store the time and another to display it in the desired format by using a formula like the following

```
=HOUR(A1)&":"&TEXT(MINUTE(A1),"00")
```

I got a message that the above formula was not working with values like `2:15 PM`. Below is an improved version, taking advantage of LAMBDA to avoid repeating HOUR(A1) multiple times.

```
=LAMBDA(_hour,(_hour-IF(_hour>12,12,0))&":"&TEXT(MINUTE(A1),"00"))(HOUR(A1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question:   I just looked expecting to find an option under **Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format** but couldn't see anything that would work.

If you do end up doing it with a formula, then the easiest approach may be to use helper columns, and something like  =if(hour(E6) > 12, hour(E6)-12, hour(E6))

(Not the answer you want, I know, but I cannot see another, and couldn't find one by experimenting either.)

Answer (score 0):

If your targeted cell is another long formula and you want to prevent writing it twice you can use two `Substitutes`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1, "h:mm am/pm"), " AM",), " PM",)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Formula

---

<sub>**Use if times are in 12-hour format (no seconds)**</sub>

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1, 5))
```

<sub>**Use if times need to be formatted**</sub>

```
=TRIM(LEFT(TEXT(A1, "h:mm a/p"), 5))
```

---

### Explanation

---

1. The [LEFT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079?hl=en) returns the first 5 characters from the time string which won't include AM or PM, but might include a space:

   ```
   =LEFT( "5:00 PM", 5)= "5:00 " ⬅ includes a space after 5:00
   =LEFT("11:00 AM", 5)= "11:00"
   ```
2. The [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en) function removes any trailing space that might be returned:

   ```
   =TRIM("5:00 ")= "5:00"  ⬅ space removed
   =TRIM("11:00")= "11:00"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in [my previous answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88916/88163), it's not possible without a formula. Below, there is a formula using the IF function. It's the same idea from [this other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88863/88163). Still, here I'm explaining a bit differently and adding a second formula to avoid dealing with the cell format by returning a text value instead of a number.

If the value of A1 is a time value, like 2:15 PM, the simplest solution is to subtract 0.5. This is because, in Google Sheets, time is handled as a serialized number where the unit is one day, the same as 24 hours.

If you want to return the value as time

```
=IF(A1>0.5,A1-0.5,A1)
```

Ensure the cell format is set to display time without PM/AM.

The formula should return a text value if you don't want to deal with the cell formatting options. Like this:

```
=TEXT(IF(A1>0.5,A1-0.5,A1),"h:mm")
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a total kludge, but if you want to do it without an extra column in your table, you can edit the format (`Format > Number > More Formats > More Time and Date Formats`) and then just insert a ton of spaces after the minutes and use the column size to hide the AM/PM part.

E.g., 
`(Hour 1)(Minutes 01)(AM/PM a)` ----->  `(Hour 1)(Minutes 01)             (AM/PM a)`

Then, just hide the am/pm text with column size.

There's a ton of reasons why this will eventually cause greater irritation than it is worth, but for something quick and dirty, I have found it to be convenient.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a formula; it's actually quite simple. If you input time is like this:
2:30 PM (with a space in the middle),
it will automatically switch your input to the 24hr equivalent. But if you input the time as 2:30pm (without a space in the middle), and THEN hit enter, it will automatically correct your input to 2:30 PM, as opposed to the military time format.

Answer (score -3):

This will show the current time like 10:00 am:

```
=HOUR(TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm"))&":"&TEXT(MINUTE(TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm")),"00")&(IF(HOUR(TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm"))<12," am"," pm"))
```

Answer (score -3):

Slightly kludgy works for goodenuf solution I just need it done:

- Leave formatting as 12 hour time format with annoying AM/PM afterwards i.e. 11:59 AM
- Right justify the cells
- Narrow the column so AM/PM is not visible

Wide times like 12:45 cut off the 5 but not enough to matter - still can read it
Everything else displays perfectly